# R - calculate pairwise orthographic similarity of a list

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I need to calculate orthographic similarity (edit/Levenshtein distance) among words in a given corpus.

The R package `vwr` seems to be able to calculate this:

```
coltheart.N(list1, list2)
```

in which the Levenshtein distance is computed pairwise between the matching words of the two word lists.

I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the Levenshtein distance between all possible word combinations of a given word list. Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `levenshtein.distance` from the package `vwr` and loop over every single word in the list:

```
library(vwr)

wordlist <- list("but", "nut", "rut")

output <- lapply(wordlist, function(x) levenshtein.distance(x, wordlist))

> output
[[1]]
but nut rut 
  0   1   1 

[[2]]
but nut rut 
  1   0   1 

[[3]]
but nut rut 
  1   1   0
```

There is a warning message about passing a list argument to `stringdist`, but the results fit, so I'm pretty sure you can ignore it.

---

Edit:

To assign the words as names for the list items, just use

```
names(output) <- wordlist

> output
$but
but nut rut 
  0   1   1 

$nut
but nut rut 
  1   0   1 

$rut
but nut rut 
  1   1   0
```

Comment: Seems to work (although it's taking a bit of time, iit's a huge list) - thanks! One more question: how can I replace `[[1]]` with the actual "source" word?